# Change the default view published in the Revit model for use in the Forge viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative

I want to publish several views (3D views, Ceiling Plan, Floor Plan), and I want to set a specific view as the default.

I tried to create different sets in "Publish Settings" in Revit, attempting to influence the order using alphabetic order, creating set orders, and adding set orders, but I am not clear if there is a way to achieve this.

I want to achieve this for ACC, Autodesk Viewer, and Forge. Is there any solution (From Revit)? [Example in Autodesk Viewer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQH5q.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any way to specify the default view on the Revit side (but perhaps somebody else is) but if you're developing your own application using Autodesk Platform services (formerly known as Autodesk Forge), this kind of feature would be easy to implement. Using the [Model Derivative service](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/developers_guide/overview/) you can find all the outputs extracted from your design file (in case of Revit, all 3D views and 2D sheets), and you can choose which of these views you want to load into the viewer by default.

Comment: I understand the idea is to develop a feature that allows the user to choose the view they want. This is because for each user, it would be a different position in the array of views. Thanks, @petr-broz. I still want to avoid that and set it up on Revit.